# How can i create an object when having @ManyToOne linking between tables

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I have 2 classes - Person and Team.
One person can be in only one team, but one team can have many people (person objects). The problem is that both Person and Team need the other class objects to create themselves.

Classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Team")
public class Team {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "teamName", nullable = false)
    private String teamName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myTeam", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set <Person> setOfMembers = new HashSet<Person>();

    public Team(int id, String teamName, Set <Person> setOfMembers) {
            //usual code (don't want to waste so much space)
    }
    ... other irrelevant fields ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "teamID", nullable = false)
    private int teamID;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "teamID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Team myTeam;

    public Person(int id, int teamID, Team myTeam) {
        //usual code
    }
    ... other irrelevant fields ...
}
```

Now in the main file, i'm trying to create a new object:

```
Team t1 = new Team(1,"Nights Watch", <and here i need Person Object, so i 
do something as follows:> new Person(1,1, <and here i need Team object>));
```

so it goes recurrent, without end.
I want to add some records to the database, but i don't know how.

Actually I need there the Set of Person Objects, but still, i don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need all your teammates during the initialization of the `Team` class ?

Just do a constructor without the `Person` argument, and then do a method like:

```java
public void addTeamMember(Person person) {
   setOfMembers.add(person);
}
```

Then, you can create the `Team`, create the `Person` and finally add the Person to the Team.